# Importing multiple custom tensor2tensor Problems in Flask

Tags: tensorflow, flask, tensorflow-serving, flask-restplus, tensor2tensor

In a flask_restplus API, I'm trying to infer from two tensor2tensor models which are being served on one server. Both these models are custom, so I am supplying t2t_usr_dir to the serving functions of tensor2tensor, such that the custom Problem could be found.

When inferring on one custom Problem, everything is fine and the results are as expected. However, when I want to infer on the second model, the program fails at

```
def get_registered_problem(usr_dir_string, problem):
    usr_dir.import_usr_dir(usr_dir_string)
    print("Importing worked?")
    problem = registry.problem(problem)
    print("Problem naam:", problem)
    return problem
```

with a `LookupError: my_custom_problem_2 not in the set of supported problems`.

When I switch back to the first model (my_custom_problem_1), everything is fine again and the logs tell me that an object  exists. I double checked that all the user and data directories are correct. It feels like a flask thing OR a `problem = registry.problem(problem)` thing, as if once a custom problem is loaded, the second user directory registration just doesn't get picked up.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you load all customized problems into a single usr_dir and initialize once, instead of trying to switch the directory and re-importing the usr_dir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that using the `usr_dir.import_usr_dir(usr_dir_string)` is not the best way to go as it seems to indeed re-import the same first usr_dir, as Matthias suggested. I solved this problem by adding the corresponding usr_dirs into my root folder and just importing them as a module.

After that I removed the `usr_dir.import_usr_dir(usr_dir_string)` line at all and proceded to register the problem via `problem = registry.problem(problem)`, which went fine for both problems!